# TRegistry - why are some keys readible and others not?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

I have written the following code:

```
var
  MainForm: TMainForm;

const
  SRootKey = HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE;
  SKey = 'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\NetworkList\Profiles';

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

{ TMainForm }

procedure TMainForm.GetKeys(OutList: TStrings);
var
  Reg: TRegistry;
begin
  OutList.BeginUpdate;
  try
    OutList.Clear;

    Reg := TRegistry.Create(KEY_READ);
    try
      Reg.RootKey := SRootKey;
      if (Reg.OpenKeyReadOnly(SKey)) and (Reg.HasSubKeys) then
      begin
        Reg.GetKeyNames(OutList);
        Reg.CloseKey;
      end;
    finally
      Reg.Free;
    end;
  finally
    OutList.EndUpdate;
  end;
end;

procedure TMainForm.btnScanClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  GetKeys(ListBox1.Items);
end;

procedure TMainForm.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  GetKeys(ListBox1.Items);
end;
```

This does not seem to do anything.

I can verify the registry path (Windows 8.1), I have even changed the `SKey` for testing and no issues, but certain keys like this one return nothing.

I even tried running the program from Windows as `Administrator` and still nothing.

Is there something else I need to change? What would make certain keys readible and others not?

Comment: I think it's time to learn about [`registry redirector`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384232%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: @TLama that is definitely new to me. I don't often use the registry so it was a bit of a suprise when today messing around with a new project it would not work. DavidHeffernan has explained it very well to me.

Comment: I see. Take that comment as an unecessary hint from me. Yet another hint is changing the time for calling `Reg.CloseKey`. Consider what happens when the key will be successfuly opened, but will have no subkeys. You will keep it opened since the `Reg.HasSubKeys` will evaluate that statement to False. Better use `if Reg.OpenKeyReadOnly() then try...finally Reg.CloseKey; end;` [P.S. I found a question where you could get your answer but kept your Q opened. People here are obviously hunting for reputation points :-)]

Comment: It often depends on the question. Sometimes it's obvious that an answer is all there is to say. They can be dealt with quickly. Other times it's good to hold fire and encourage other opinions and contributions.

Comment: @TLama the key will be closed when reg is destroyed so may as well remove CloseKey

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your process is 32 bit, and you are running it on a 64 bit machine. As such you are subject to [registry redirection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384232.aspx).

> The registry redirector isolates 32-bit and 64-bit applications by providing separate logical views of certain portions of the registry on WOW64. The registry redirector intercepts 32-bit and 64-bit registry calls to their respective logical registry views and maps them to the corresponding physical registry location. The redirection process is transparent to the application. Therefore, a 32-bit application can access registry data as if it were running on 32-bit Windows even if the data is stored in a different location on 64-bit Windows.

The key you are looking at

```
HKLM\SOFTWARE
```

is redirected. From your 32 bit process, attempts to open this key are redirected to the 32 bit view of the registry, which as an implementation detail, is stored at

```
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node
```

What you are trying to do here is to access the 64 bit view of the registry. To do so you need to [access an alternate registry view](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384129.aspx). That means passing the `KEY_WOW64_64KEY` key when opening any keys.

In Delphi you can achieve that by including `KEY_WOW64_64KEY` in the `Access` flags, or by including it in the flags you pass to the constructor.

```
Reg := TRegistry.Create(KEY_READ or KEY_WOW64_64KEY);
```

On top of that, for this particular key, due to the registry security configuration for this key, you need to be running with admin rights in order to open the key. Even if you only intend to read it.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to explain it. I had to assume the issue was something to do with Windows but I just could not find out what it was.